# Is my bracketing the issue here? Or is there really an unexpected identifier? Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a simple app that increases the count below each picture on click. I think it's having an issue compiling or I'm missing something silly and obvious.

Heres my HTML and JS

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Cat Clicker </h1>
    <img class="catpic_one" src="cat.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
    <p class="counter_one"> 0 </p>
    <img class="catpic_two" src="catpic2.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
    <p class="counter_two"> 0 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var clicks_one = 0;
var clicks_two = 0;


    $('#catpic_one').on("click", "#counter_one", function() {
        clicks_one++
        var clickcount_one = clicks_one.toString();
            $('#counter_one').append("You clicked the cat #1" clickcount_one " times."); 
    }


    $('#catpic_two').on("click", "#counter_two", function() {
        clicks_two++
        var clickcount_two = clicks_two.toString();
            $('#counter_two').append("You clicked the cat #1" clickcount_two " times."); 
    }



});
```

Comment: `$('#catpic_two').on("click", "#counter_two"` ? What are you expecting here ?

Comment: You aren't concatenating strings properly, and you seem to have misunderstood the use of delegated event handlers as `#catpic_one` is not a parent of `#counter_one`.

Answer (score 2):

catpic_one and catpic_two are class, not id. please change from `'#'to '.'`, as

```
'.catpic_one' and '.catpic_two'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax error in your concatenation, you have not declared any element with ids.
And you are trying to access using id selector.
$('#counter_one')

- put id property to 'p' tag, if you want to use # selector.
- Correct the concatenations as suggested in other answers.
- As a good practice, always include end tag for all elements.
- Also, this is javascript. It is not required to convert element to string.

> var clickcount_two = clicks_two.toString();

You can directly concatenate variable in a string.